# Unable to get the record based on struct value from datastore using golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am writing a service for search functionality.  when i am passing values in the body to get the specific record i am unable to get it based on the struct value.
ex:phone number or username

**Edit1:**

```
type PatientData struct {
    ID            int64    datastore:"-"
    FirstName     string   json:"firstname,omitempty"
    LastName      string   json:"lastname,omitempty"
    UserName      string   json:"username,omitempty"
    Phone         string   json:"phone,omitempty"     
}
```

I want to get the full struct values based on Username or Phone. Below is  my code:

```
func searchValue (res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){

    log.Printf("%#v Getting values url - x ", "called search")

    patient := &PatientData{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(patient); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
    ctx, err := appengine.Namespace(ctx, NAMESPACENAME)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    m := patient.Phone
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(m, 10, 64)
    log.Printf("%#v Getting values m ", m)
    log.Printf("%#v Getting values url -yyy ",i)

    key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "Patient","" , i, nil)
    log.Printf("%#v Getting values url - key ", key)
    err = datastore.Get(ctx, key, patient)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(res).Encode(patient); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

As i am passing PHONE in my Newkey i am unable to generate  the values based on PHONE

I don't want to use Newkey in put functionality to generate a keyname and based on that KEYNAME i dont want to get Values.

Comment: You gotta give more details than that. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: I am Just editing my post with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`datastore.Get()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Get) can only be used to get an entity from the datastore by its key, so its key must be known / present.

This is obviously not what you're trying to do. You are trying to fetch entities by properties which are not the key. To do that, you need to run a *query*.

Datastore queries are represented by the [`datastore.Query`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query) type. You need to create a query and set filters on it. In your case, you want to filter by the username and/or phone properties.

This is how it could look like. Fetch patient entities filtered by phone:

```
q :=  datastore.NewQuery("Patient").Filter("phone =", patient.Phone)

var patients []*Patient
keys, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &patients)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return
}

// patients contains patients with the given phone number
```

An example fetching patients filtered by phone number AND user name:

```
q :=  datastore.NewQuery("Patient").
    Filter("phone =", patient.Phone).
    Filter("username =", patient.UserName)

var patients []*Patient
keys, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &patients)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return
}

// patients contains patients with the given phone number and username
```

Comment: Thank you for your help 
But I have a conflict that the end user should search with either PHONE or FIRSTNAME or LASTNAME of the patient.
can you help me how to  solve this.

Comment: @SrinathReddy You mean only one condition is used in the query, or there are multiple conditions with logical OR connection in one query?

Comment: with logical OR connection in one query

Comment: @SrinathReddy Datastore queries generally do not support logical OR connection. I believe some support was added but what it does is it runs multiple queries in parallel, and merges the result. I don't think the Golang query API contains this though. Your best bet is to run those multiple queries yourself, and merge the results.

Comment: Really i don't have any solution for my problem

Comment: @SrinathReddy If for example you want patients where firstName is "Bob" OR lastName is "Smith", then you run 2 queries: one where you only filter by `firstname=Bob`, and the other where you only filter by `lastName=Smith`. Now you have 2 patient slices, and you "merge" these by appending patients from the 2nd slice to the first that are not yet in the first slice. And the result will be the first slice.

Comment: I am new to the coding .can you help me to sort out the solution

Comment: @SrinathReddy You should post that as a new, follow-up question, linking to this as the original.